# internal error. ERROR: PleskFatalException: Unable to connect to database: Unknown database 'psa' (auth.php:149)

Tags: mysql, database

I have a lDebian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy) server.
After some troubles with MYSQL server I made a backup for my databases and reinstalled MYSQL server with plesk parallel panel.
I wanted to restore the old backup content in `/var/lib/mysql/` and some how I droped the psa table, and now once I try to access parallels with my browser i recieve this message:

```
internal error. ERROR: PleskFatalException: Unable to connect to database: Unknown database 'psa' (auth.php:149)
```

What I know now is that I have dropped psa database and I have to retore it from the backup of the new mysql installation

typing this command  `ls -la /var/lib/psa/dumps/` shows me that I have a compressed backup for my database `mysql.daily.dump.0.gz` I dont know what this compressed file do contain I mean is that only my psa database or there is others databases, and how to restore only psa database under `/var/lib/mysql`

#### Edit

I found this solution:

```
zcat /var/lib/psa/dumps/mysql.preupgrade.<version and time stamp>.dump.gz | sed -n '/-- Current Database: `psa`/,/-- Current Database:*/p' | mysql -f -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

Could someone explain it to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Login to MYSQL

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

2.Check if this database is really deleted:

```
mysql> show databases like 'psa';
```

if you get:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

that means that the database was dropped
you can check also like this:

```
use psa;
```

if you get `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'psa'` the database is then dropped

3.upload the database from the bacup copy:

3.1 search for the latest backup copy:

```
ls -lt /var/lib/psa/dumps/mysql.daily.dump*
```

3.2 unzip it  `mysql.daily.dump.0.gz` should be your newest copy

```
gunzip /var/lib/psa/dumps/mysql.daily.dump.0.gz
```

3.3 create an empty psa database

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -e "create database psa"
```

3.4 restore your data: from the unzipped backup file to the new database

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa < /var/lib/psa/dumps/mysql.daily.dump.0
```

### PS:

solution was found in this link, I tested it and it works fine for me
[link for the original answer](http://kb.parallels.com/en/119089)

Comment: you literally made my day. This is the only solution that worked.

Comment: I love stackoverflow!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU